# Layover in Hong Kong

Tags: airports, layovers

I am a US citizen. Going back to NY, I have a 15-hour layover in Hong Kong. I'll arrive at Hong Kong airport at 8:30 pm, and the flight to NY is at 5:00 pm. I need a cheap place to stay. How do I get to Central from the airport? What safe transportation to get? Do I need a visa?

Comment: Define 'cheap'.

Comment: The answers below reflect my experience in HK as well, though what I'm concerned about here is the math. If you get to HKG at 8:30pm then a 15 hour layover has you leaving at 11:30am. On the other hand, if you're leaving at 5:00pm that's a 20.5 hour layover. So, which is it? The length of time you're actually there could be relevant to the answers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](/help) Moreover, "cheap" is a matter of opinion since what is cheap for you might not be cheap for me. In addition, you ask several questions in one whereas they should really be separated in dedicated posts. Hence why I am voting to close as too broad. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works. Moreover, don't forget to search for questions similar to yours before posting.

Answer (score 1):

`I need a cheap place to stay.` and `How do I get to Central` don't go well together. Central being the most expensive area in Hong Kong.

To answer the question about transportation, the most convenient and fastest is the Airport Express: there's a train from the airport to Hong Kong station (in Central) every 12 minutes, and it takes 24 minutes.

This train has a couple of stops on the way, which could be possibilities to find cheaper accommodation than in Central. Of course "cheap" is a relative term. Depending on your budget, there could be places on the Island that could be suitable for you.

Going back to the airport the next day, you can check-in downtown at the Airport Express train station, before taking the train to the airport. This is quite convenient, as you won't have to carry your luggage to the airport.

As for the visa, US citizens do not need a visa for Hong Kong and Macau.

Answer (score 1):

Hong Kong and "cheap" don't go together well.

Hotel in the airport will run you at least US$200 / night but it's convenient and you don't have to pay for transportation. Close to the airport are a bunch of fairly affordable AirBnBs but availability is hit or miss and you probably will need a taxi to get there.

Kowloon may be a good compromise. You should be able to get a workable room for a US$100 or so.

Not sure how often you get to Hong Kong: it's a great place to visit and walking along the Avenue of the Stars or taking the Star Ferry is almost free. You may spend a few extra dollars to get the experience.

Comment: You should specify currency. It looks like those prices are USD.